# how append dataframe to dataframe with duplicate id

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

i have a dataframe df1

```
 id  Name  City   type 
 1   Anna  Paris   AB
 2   Marc   Rome   D
 3   erika  madrid AC
```

and a dataframe df2

```
 id  Name  City   type 
 1   Anna  Paris   B
```

and a dataframe   df3

```
 id  Name  City   type 
 1   Anna  Paris   C
```

i want to append df2 and df3 to df1 , this is my expected output :

```
 id  Name  City   type 
 1   Anna  Paris   AB
 2   Marc   Rome   D
 3   erika  madrid AC
 1   Anna  Paris   B
 1   Anna  Paris   C

df1  = df1.append(df2)
df1  = df1.append(df3)
```

but the dataframe add only the last row and  delete the other rows  with the same id

```
 id  Name  City   type 
 2   Marc   Rome   D
 3   erika  madrid AC
 1   Anna  Paris   C
```

i mtrying also concat

```
df1= pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], join='inner')
```

Comment: So you need `df1= pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])` ?

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with `pd.concat()` is that you are passing the parameter `join = inner`. I expect this to work:

```
output = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

Using this an example code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna','Marc','erika'],
                    'City':['Paris','Rome','madrid'],
                    'Type':['AB','D','AC']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna'],
                    'City':['Paris'],
                    'Type':['B']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anna'],
                    'City':['Paris'],
                    'Type':['C']})
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

It outputs:

```
    Name    City Type
0   Anna   Paris   AB
1   Marc    Rome    D
2  erika  madrid   AC
0   Anna   Paris    B
0   Anna   Paris    C
```

Comment: same output , it keeps only last row with the same id , weird !